# Joomla Akeeba Backup exclude database table column

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I am using a combination of Joomla 3.x/Hikashop/Akeeba Backup for staging between my dev and production sites. I understand that from Akeeba, I can configure database tables to exclude, however I need to exclude a very specific column from a table when migrating from my dev to production. so for example `#_hikashop_product` contains the column of `product_quantity` that needs to retain its value on the production side since the dev does not have values. If I exclude the entire product table, I would be excluding updates to products my clients have made.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create a PHP script that will run after Akeeba to copy the contents of the product table. The product table should be excluded from the Akeeba backup.